# hydrated_bloc not persisting data

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm building a flutter app that uses BLoC pattern and using hydrated_bloc package to persist data.

The bloc itself is working fine, ie the event comes into the bloc and the bloc yields a state back to the ui.

The issue is that the bloc is not saving the json with the hydrated_bloc.

Here's the code for the bloc and event:

```
enum ConditionsEvent { snowyPressed, sunnyPressed, rainyPressed }

class ConditionsBloc extends HydratedBloc<ConditionsEvent, String> {
  ConditionsBloc() : super('unknown');

  @override
  Stream<String> mapEventToState(ConditionsEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case ConditionsEvent.snowyPressed:
        yield 'Snowy';
        break;
      case ConditionsEvent.sunnyPressed:
        yield 'Sunny';
        break;
      case ConditionsEvent.rainyPressed:
        yield 'Rainy';
        break;
    }
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(String state) {
    return <String, String>{'conditions': state};
  }

  @override
  String fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => json['value'] as String;

}
```

How can I get this to save the data in local storage using hydrated_bloc, so that when the user restarts app, the data is persisted? I think the problem is with `toJson` and `fromJson`.

Comment: toJson - conditions fromJson - value

Answer (score 6):

You made a mistake in the fromJSON while copy-pasta.
You need to use json['**conditions**'] instead of json['**value**'].

```
 @override
  String fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => json['conditions'] as String;
```